# React Native: Re-use rendered image

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, jsx

I'm trying to build something like a "Logo Wall", but there might be (and often are) identical images. When rendering them, they will be loaded each separately, even if a same image url already has been fetched.

Here is my code:

```
export default class LogoWall extends React.Component
{
    //...

    renderLogo(logoUrl)
    {
        // need to wrap into a function to have unique keys...
        return (key) => <Image
            key={key}
            source={{uri: logoUrl}}
            style={styles.logo}
        />
    }

    render()
    {
        // trying to save logos within this object
        const logos = {};

        return (
            <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
                {(() => {
                    let logoRows = [];

                    for (let i = 0; i < this.props.rows; i++) {
                        logoRows.push(<View style={styles.logoRow} key={i}>
                            {this.getLogos(i % 2 === 0).map((logoUrl, key) => {

                                // should only render when this image doesn't exist
                                if (typeof logos[logoUrl] === 'undefined') {
                                    logos[logoUrl] = this.renderLogo(logoUrl);
                                }

                                return logos[logoUrl](key)
                            })}
                        </View>)
                    }

                    return logoRows;
                })()}
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

How could I improve this to load one image only once, but having them displayed multiple times (without refetch)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain the image gets fetched again? Have you checked network activity to verify? I'd be a little surprised if react-native doesn't already do some caching, but I'll assume they do not for the benefit of your answer and because there are solutions out there such as...

https://github.com/kfiroo/react-native-cached-image

If you use this package, you'd just need to replace...

```
<Image
    key={key}
    source={{uri: logoUrl}}
    style={styles.logo}
 />
```

with

```
<CachedImage
    key={key}
    source={{uri: logoUrl}}
    style={styles.logo}
 />
```

But please verify whether redundant fetches are actually happening and let us know. Also, this package uses native modules, so it assumes you're willing to eject from expo (or CRNA), or are using a standard `react-native init` based app. You didn't mention which you were using. If you need a javascript based solution, then you might try [memoizing](https://medium.com/@lunasunkaiser/functional-memoization-in-javascript-adec62508bd0) your `renderLogo` function.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes I can confirm it's getting refetched, because when the wall contains e.g. 20 logos, each one gets rendered one by one with a delay of ~1s (also checked network activity). Once they are downloaded, they are cached (but only after restarting app). What I actually want is to access the rendered instance of an image. When I store them into a variable (like shown above), it tries to refetch (or use cache after restarting app). So I need a way to store the rendered instance of it, so it won't re-render it.

Comment: It's a great problem to solve. I'd love to learn of any solution you find. Would be useful in core too I'd imagine